# Change root password of instance in Amazon EC 2 & Webmin

Tags: amazon-ec2, instance, webmin

I have set up a website with the help of a System Admin on Amazon EC2. After the work, he installed a Webmin for me to handle the things like Control Panel. Now I need to reset the password for everything to keep things secure. For this:

(a) I have changed all users password including root user from Webmin interface
(b) Change the password associated with EC2 account.

But do it need to change the password of the EC 2 instance? Or it is already changed when I edited the password of the root user from Webmin ?

Answer (score 2):

No, the password of the instances are unrelated to those of the amazon passwords. You'd be better of using key pairs than passwords for this reason.

Comment: What I understand is, its not possible to change the Instance password. right ?

Comment: It is, if you go into each instance and change it with the passwd command.

Comment: I have created a new instance. Then connect to server via SSH. Only on the first time, it allows me to use root user and there after I used the user "ubuntu". Then I changed the password of the user but no effect while connecting. Even after password change, I can access without entering any password.. Only needed those .pem file. What I conclude is, remove SSH from rules list, so noone can connect.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @HirenSagar is correct.

You cannot access your webmin instance without a password.

EC2 instances dont have passwords by default.

But you can side-step that by manually setting a password and user for your webmin.

First update your apt:

`sudo apt-get update`

Then:

`sudo /usr/share/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin root yourpassword`

Root is the webmin user and password is its password.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the password of your instance it will protect your data from the hacker. Please set a strong password for your instance. A password should be a combination of uppercase letter (A,B,C,D), lowercase letter (a,b,c,d), numbers (1,2,3,4) and special character (@,#,&). A weak password is easily hacked by the hacker.

You can change the password of your instance by login into your AWS control panel:

```
Step 1: Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
Step 2: In the navigation pane, choose Instances and then choose the instance that needs a password reset. ...
Step 3: Choose Actions, Instance Settings, Get System Log.
Step 4: Locate the EC2 Agent entry, for example, EC2 Agent: Ec2Config service v3.18.1118.
```

Comment: The question was "Do I need to and how do I change the password of the EC 2 instance?", not "How do I change the password of the linux root account"

Comment: FalcoGer, Thank you for your valuable feedback! I've made some tweak changes on the steps on how to change the password from the AWS EC2.

Answer (score 0):

hi u could not change password of EC2, It has a Keypair, (.pem file to convert .ppk file through putty key generator) when u created EC2 instance From Aws, 
make sure you have to give SSH Assess to your ip Address From Security Group (AWS-EC2-Inbound rules) then you can SSH from putty and manage Ubuntu terminal 
User name Ubuntu, pass if created that or upload ppk for open terminal,
after login, 
if u wann reset or change pass of webmin
you should try this

1 sudo apt-get update
2 sudo /usr/share/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin root yourpass;
3 sudo /etc/init.d/webmin restart